# Kfold validation_data in Keras model.fit using Sci-Kit Learn GridsearchCV

Tags: keras, scikit-learn, gridsearchcv, k-fold

I'm working with Keras, using Sci-Kit Learn gridsearchcv and Kold and SciKeras wrappers.
I would to pass the validation folders of Kfold to the fit method of the model, by means of the parameter validation_data. I tried some alternatives but I can't do it. Here's the code.

```
NN = KerasClassifier(
  model=get_NN,
  X_len = len(X_train.columns),
  loss="mse",
  optimizer="SGD",
  epochs=300,
  batch_size=4,
  shuffle=True,
  verbose=False,
  # fit__validation_data = # Here I should pass the validation data
  callbacks=[
    tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(
      monitor="val_loss", min_delta=0.0001, patience=15, restore_best_weights=True
    )
  ]
)

custom_scores_monk = {
    "accuracy": "accuracy",
    "mse": make_scorer(mean_squared_error,greater_is_better=False)
}

NN_MONK1_GRID_DICT = {
  "model__lr" : [0.5], 
  "model__alpha" : [0.8],
  "model__hidden_activation" : ["tanh"],
  "model__neurons" : [4], 
  "model__initializer" : ["glorot"], 
  "model__nesterov" : [True], 
  "model__penalty": [None], 
  "model__lambda_reg": [None],
  "model__seed" : [15]
}

grid = GridSearchCV(NN,
                    param_grid=NN_MONK1_GRID_DICT,
                    scoring=custom_scores_monk,
                    refit="mse",
                    cv=CV,
                    return_train_score=True,
                    n_jobs=-1
        )
```

Between the others alternatives, I tried writing a custom callback for updating the data set on_train_begin, but It seems to be a dirty practice, I'm not surprised It doesn't work.

```
class ValidationCallback(Callback):
  def __init__(self, X, y, validation_split):
    super().__init__()
    self.X = X
    self.y = y
    self.validation_split = validation_split
    self.count = 0

  def on_train_begin(self, logs=None):
    print("Training " + str(self.count))
    indexes = self.validation_split[self.count]
    X_val, y_val = [self.X.iloc[i] for i in indexes], [self.y.iloc[i] for i in indexes]
    self.count = self.count+1
    self.model.fit__validation_data = (X_val, y_val)
```

Instead, I'm very surprised there is no a solution for a so common task as the KFold cross validation, especially using framework as skl.
In particular, this problem leads to the impossibility to use 'val_loss' as monitor value for early stopping, apart from the impossibility to plot and compare training and validation learning curves.

Do You have solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent about a week on that and I finally found a way.

**Short answer**: don't do it. Just handwrite an ad-hoc method for grid search and use it.

**Long answer**: you can define a subclass of the SciKeras' wrapper, in order to redefine the `fit` method passing the current fold to it.
To do that, you must:

1. know the fold that will be used, and thus you must set a `random_state` in your CV object

```
    # define a split strategy using a random_state
    CV = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, random_state=42, shuffle=True)
    
    # get the validation folds
    val_split = [ test for (train, test) in CV.split(X_train, y_train) ]
    
    val_data = [ 
      (
        [X_train.iloc[i].tolist() for i in indexes], 
        [y_train.iloc[i].tolist() for i in indexes]
      ) for indexes in val_split 
    ]
```

2. define a *"static"* counter for the folds

```
    # static fold counter
    def count():
      count.count += 1
      return count.count
    
    def reset_counter():
      count.count =-1
    
    def get_count():
      return count.count
```

3. in the same way, you must define a registry for memorizing the various `history` objects

```
    # static history register
    def histories():
      histories.histories = []
    
    def register(h):
      histories.histories.append(h)
    
    def get_histories():
      return histories.histories
    
    def clear_histories():
      histories()
```

4. define a method for computing the mean of the histories. It allows to do early stopping on the *validation loss*.

```
    # utilities to get the mean of K histories
    
    def add_padding(ls, n):
      ls.extend([ls[-1]] * n)
      return ls
    
    def mean_epochs(l):
      return int(mean([ len(item['loss']) for item in l ]))
    
    def mean_history(_histories):
      m = mean_epochs(_histories)+1
      for history in _histories:
        l = len(history['loss'])
        for field in _histories[0]:
          if l>= m:
            history[field] = history[field][:m]
          else:
            history[field] = add_padding(history[field], (m-l))
      return \
        { field : 
            [ 
              (sum(x)/len(_histories)) for x in zip(
                *[ history[field] for history in _histories ]
              )
            ] for field in _histories[0]
        }
```

5. extend the SciKeras wrapper class, redefining the `fit` method

```
    # KerasClassifier Wrapper for kfold
    class KCWrapper(KerasClassifier):
    
      # you can pass the same parameters you passed to the KerasClassifier, after val_data and k
      def __init__(self, val_data, k, *args, **kwargs):
        super(KCWrapper, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.val_data = val_data
        self.k = k
      
      def fit(self, X, y, **kwargs):
        h = super().fit(X, y, validation_data=self.val_data[count()], **kwargs)
        register(h.history_)
        # do_NN_plot(h.history_)  # plot single fold curve
        if self.kfold_finished(): # plot mean of k folds curves
          do_NN_plot(mean_history(get_histories()))
        
      def kfold_finished(self):
        return self.k == get_count()+1
```

6. instantiate the (wrapper of the wrapper of the) classifier

```
    # Define grids for gridsearchcv
    kerasClassifierParams = {
      "model" : get_NN,
      "X_len" : len(X_train.columns),
      "loss" : "mse",
      "optimizer" : "SGD",
      "epochs" : 300,
      "batch_size" : 4,
      "shuffle" : True,
      "verbose" : False
    }

    NN = KCWrapper(
      val_data,
      5, # 5-Fold
      callbacks=[
        tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(
          monitor="val_loss", min_delta=0.0001, patience=20, restore_best_weights=True
        )
      ],
      **kerasClassifierParams
    )
```

The provided code also uses a routine for plotting data:

```
    def do_NN_plot(history):
    
      # Plot Accuracy
      plt.plot(history['binary_accuracy'])
      plt.plot(history['val_binary_accuracy'], linestyle="--", color="orange")
      plt.title(f'model accuracy')
      plt.ylabel('accuracy')
      plt.xlabel('epoch')
      plt.legend(['training', 'test'], loc='lower right')
      plt.show()
    
      # Plot loss
      plt.plot(history['loss'])
      plt.plot(history['val_loss'],  linestyle="--", color="orange")
      plt.title(f'model MSE')
      plt.ylabel('MSE')
      plt.xlabel('epoch')
      plt.legend(['training', 'test'], loc='upper right')
      plt.show()
```

If you're working on a regression task, you can do the same thing with a wrapper of (a wrapper of) a regressor:

```
    # define a split strategy using a random_state
    CV = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, random_state=42, shuffle=True)
    
    # get the validation folds
    val_split = [ test for (train, test) in CV.split(X_train, y_train) ]
    
    val_data = [ 
      (
        [X_train.iloc[i].tolist() for i in indexes], 
        [y_train.iloc[i].tolist() for i in indexes]
      ) for indexes in val_split 
    ]

    # static fold counter
    def count():
      count.count += 1
      return count.count
    
    def reset_counter():
      count.count =-1
    
    def get_count():
      return count.count

    # static history register
    def histories():
      histories.histories = []
    
    def register(h):
      histories.histories.append(h)
    
    def get_histories():
      return histories.histories
    
    def clear_histories():
      histories()

    # utilities to get the mean of K histories
    
    def add_padding(ls, n):
      ls.extend([ls[-1]] * n)
      return ls
    
    def mean_epochs(l):
      return int(mean([ len(item['loss']) for item in l ]))
    
    def mean_history(_histories):
      m = mean_epochs(_histories)+1
      for history in _histories:
        l = len(history['loss'])
        for field in _histories[0]:
          if l>= m:
            history[field] = history[field][:m]
          else:
            history[field] = add_padding(history[field], (m-l))
      return \
        { field : 
            [ 
              (sum(x)/len(_histories)) for x in zip(
                *[ history[field] for history in _histories ]
              )
            ] for field in _histories[0]
        }

    def do_NN_plot(history):
    
      # Plot Accuracy
      plt.plot(history['binary_accuracy'])
      plt.plot(history['val_binary_accuracy'], linestyle="--", color="orange")
      plt.title(f'model accuracy')
      plt.ylabel('accuracy')
      plt.xlabel('epoch')
      plt.legend(['training', 'test'], loc='lower right')
      plt.show()
    
      # Plot loss
      plt.plot(history['loss'])
      plt.plot(history['val_loss'],  linestyle="--", color="orange")
      plt.title(f'model MSE')
      plt.ylabel('MSE')
      plt.xlabel('epoch')
      plt.legend(['training', 'test'], loc='upper right')
      plt.show()


    # KerasRegressor Wrapper for kfold
    class KRWrapper(KerasRegressor):
    
      def __init__(self, val_data, k, *args, **kwargs):
        super(KRWrapper, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.val_data = val_data
        self.k = k
        
      def fit(self, X, y, **kwargs):
        h = super().fit(X, y, validation_data=self.val_data[count()], **kwargs)
        register(h.history_)
        # do_NN_plot(h.history_)  # plot single fold curve
        if self.kfold_finished(): # plot mean of k folds curves
          do_NN_plot(mean_history(get_histories()))
        
      def kfold_finished(self):
        return self.k == get_count()+1

    # Define grids for gridsearchcv
    kerasRegressorParams = {
      "model" : get_NN,
      "X_len" : len(X_train.columns),
      "loss" : mee_NN,
      "optimizer" : "SGD", # fixed into get_NN
      "batch_size" : 32,
      "epochs" : 2000,
      "shuffle" : True,
      "verbose" : 0
    }
    
    NN = KRWrapper(
      val_data,
      5,
      callbacks=[
        tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(
          monitor="val_loss", min_delta=0.000001, patience=50, restore_best_weights=True
        )
      ],
      **kerasRegressorParams
    )
```

This satisfied my curiosity and stubbornness, but it's a dirty solution (even if it's still a solution :P).
How I said at the beginning: just handwrite an ad-hoc method for grid search and use it. The solution presented above doesn't allow to use the intrinsic parallelization of the Skl's GridsearchCV, so it's a lot of completely useless work.

**Note:** the approach that uses the callback didn't work because the parameters of the `fit` method are passed before the callback is invoked. Thus when the callback is invoked, the setted `fit__validation_data` is no evaluated.